# How to Dispose of Database and Connection properly

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, visual-studio-2013, data-binding

In my C# app, I have a list of catalogs that I want the user to be able to display and update on a grid.

To make this work I display the grid and set the Update command, so the MsAccess database will update whenever the user changes something in the Grid.

Whenever a "Some thing catalog" button is pressed, the UpdateGrid function is run. This function receives the name of the table and the Update query, with a list of parameters to make the update.

```
private void UpdateGrid(string data, string queryUpdate, List<Tuple<string, OleDbType,int>> parameters, bool Fuse, string description)
{

    tblName.Text = description;

    try
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = (Fuse ? new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Fusing.mdb") : new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=MaterialDB.mdb"));

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + data, conn);

        myDataSet = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(myDataSet, data);
        DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[data];

        // Create the UpdateCommand.
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryUpdate, conn);

        // Add the parameters for the UpdateCommand.
        foreach (var param in parameters)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@" + param.Item1, param.Item2, param.Item3, param.Item1);
        }
        command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer, 5, "ID");
        adapter.UpdateCommand = command;

        // Update the DB whenever a row changes
        myDataTable.RowChanged += (s, f) =>
        {
            adapter.Update(myDataTable);
        };
        var be = CatalogsGrid.GetBindingExpression(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty);

        CatalogsGrid.DataContext = myDataSet;
        CatalogsGrid.ItemsSource = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        Binding nbe = new Binding
        {
            Source = myDataSet,
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
            Path = new PropertyPath(data),
            BindsDirectlyToSource = true
        };
        CatalogsGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, nbe);

        CatalogsGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

This function works as intended.

However, I tried to follow the Disposing guidelines, and put a `using` in each database element. When I do this, and everything becomes:

```
using(OleDbConnection conn = (Fuse ? new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Fusing.mdb") : new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=MaterialDB.mdb")))
{ }
```

Then the update stops working with a generic error that tells you the Update query is wrong.

Should I put using around each `Connetion`, `DataAdapter` and `Command`, or just let them die whenever C# decides.

EDIT:

The code with using is the next:

```
private void UpdateGrid(string data, string queryUpdate, List<Tuple<string, OleDbType,int>> parameters, bool Fuse, string description)
{

    tblName.Text = description;

    try

    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = (Fuse ? new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Fusing.mdb") : new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=MaterialDB.mdb")))
        {
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + data, conn))
            {

                myDataSet = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(myDataSet, data);
                DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[data];

                // Create the UpdateCommand.
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryUpdate, conn))
                {

                    // Add the parameters for the UpdateCommand.
                    foreach (var param in parameters)
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add("@" + param.Item1, param.Item2, param.Item3, param.Item1);
                    }
                    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer, 5, "ID");
                    adapter.UpdateCommand = command;

                    // Update the DB whenever a row changes
                    myDataTable.RowChanged += (s, f) =>
                    {
                        adapter.Update(myDataTable);
                    };
                    var be = CatalogsGrid.GetBindingExpression(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty);

                    CatalogsGrid.DataContext = myDataSet;
                    CatalogsGrid.ItemsSource = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                    Binding nbe = new Binding
                    {
                        Source = myDataSet,
                        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                        Path = new PropertyPath(data),
                        BindsDirectlyToSource = true
                    };
                    CatalogsGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, nbe);

                    CatalogsGrid.Items.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

When this code is run, I get the following exception.

[image: exception]

Which my search on the internet said that this is a generic error for whatever error happened in the database update process, and 99% of the time is not an error in the query (and we know this is not the case, because before we put in the place the using statements, everything was working properly).

Comment: Always use `using` blocks for your disposables. Please also see [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements). Also your empty catch is very bad practice, you are swallowing the exception and do nothing with it. You will have no idea in the future why something stops working if you leave that in. Either log the exception and recover or do not catch at all (remove the try/catch entirely).

Comment: You should put `using` around everything that implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @MichaelGunter - that is a link (and code) to the `OleDbConnection`. Still seems valid though as it ihnerits from `DataAdapter` which inherits from `Component` which implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: @MichaelGunter Oh darn.  Thanks I didn't see it on `Component`.  That'll teach me to comment past my bed time ;)

Comment: `Then the update stops working with a generic error that tells you the Update query is wrong.` <= it would help more if you posted the code **with** the `using` statements and the `Exception` (and its details) that is being thrown after you do this.

Comment: @Igor Added details of the exception given by the database.

Comment: What does disposing your connections have to do with that Adapter error?

Comment: I got a feeling its because of `CatalogsGrid`, seems this is a UI component and the data is probably being pulled after the code executes via a binding and by then the dispose has executed as the method has exited.

Comment: @LarsTech I'm not disposing just of the connection, too the dataadapter and the command. I think one of them is being disposed before the Grid tries to use it (the DataAdapter should be it), and then everything stops working.

Comment: Try calling `CatalogsGrid.DataBind();` at the end of your code (*right after or instead of `CatalogsGrid.Items.Refresh();`*) before you exit out of the `using` scopes. This should force binding to occur before the Db objects have been disposed.

Comment: @Igor It is a DataGrid, already ran the SetBinding two lines before exiting the 'using', and there is no such thing as a DataBind() on DataGrid.

Comment: What kind of app (there are various DataGrid implementations out there). WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, something else?

Comment: @Igor Added the respective tags, it a WPF app developed under VS2013, connected to a MSAccess database, displaying tables into a DataGrid